# I want to launch my app from google now....can anyone help me with the code

Tags: android

I have been trying to launch the main activity of my app by voice searching it using google now...Can anyone help me with the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="My Voice Activated App" >
</searchable>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.authorwjf.myvoiceactivatedapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.authorwjf.myvoiceactivatedapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I wrote this code to search my app using command -"Okay Google..... Open My Voice Activated App" but this is not working

Comment: be more specific; say what you've tried and explain your problem further

Answer (score 0):

Say your app name stored in `@string/app_name` .   Your app will reflect in search result (phone)

Comment: Then what is the use of having a android label in searchable.xml??

Comment: `android:label="My Voice Activated App" >` changed to `android:label="Your app name" >`